# File size differ when received on server after encryption

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, cryptography

After implementing the cryptography on Xamarin on the PCL library the Android worked with encryption and decryption normally but IOS it's not decrypting on the server know that I changed and double checked both private and public keys that are generated automatically for the device and I set them also manually but still same error.

Code Used for encryption/Decryption

```
  public static string EncryptFile(string ChannelId, string inputFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                string resultFilePath = "";
                var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(inputFilePath);
                resultFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFilePath) + @"/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + fileInfo.Extension;
                using (var symmetricCypher = new AesManaged())
                {
                    // Generate random key and IV for symmetric encryption
                    var key = new byte[symmetricCypher.KeySize / 8];
                    var iv = new byte[symmetricCypher.BlockSize / 8];
                    using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
                    {
                        rng.GetBytes(key);
                        rng.GetBytes(iv);
                    }

                    // Encrypt the symmetric key and IV
                    var buf = new byte[key.Length + iv.Length];
                    Array.Copy(key, buf, key.Length);
                    Array.Copy(iv, 0, buf, key.Length, iv.Length);
                    buf = EncryptData(buf, ChannelId);

                    var bufLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(buf.Length);

                    // Symmetrically encrypt the data and write it to the file, along with the encrypted key and iv
                    using (var cypherKey = symmetricCypher.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
                    using (var fsIn = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                    using (var fsOut = new FileStream(resultFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(fsOut, cypherKey, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        fsOut.Write(bufLen, 0, bufLen.Length);
                        fsOut.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                        fsIn.CopyTo(cs);
                        /* var xx = fsOut.ToArray()*/
                        ;
                    }
                    File.Delete(inputFilePath);
                    return resultFilePath;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }

  public static byte[] EncryptData(byte[] data, string ChannelId)
        {
            try
            {
                var publicKey = GetChannelPublicKey(ChannelId);

                var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
                encryptEngine.Init(true, publicKey);

                return encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(data, 0, data.Length);

            }
            catch (Exception eex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(eex);
                throw;
            }

        }

        public static void DecryptFile(byte[] fileBytes, string outputFilePath, string ChannelId)
        {
            using (var symmetricCypher = new AesManaged())

            using (var fsIn = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
            {
                //symmetricCypher.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
                // Determine the length of the encrypted key and IV
                var buf = new byte[sizeof(int)];
                fsIn.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                var bufLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(buf, 0);

                // Read the encrypted key and IV data from the file and decrypt using the asymmetric algorithm
                buf = new byte[bufLen];
                fsIn.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                buf = DecryptData(buf, ChannelId);

                var key = new byte[symmetricCypher.KeySize / 8];
                var iv = new byte[symmetricCypher.BlockSize / 8];
                Array.Copy(buf, key, key.Length);
                Array.Copy(buf, key.Length, iv, 0, iv.Length);

                // Decript the file data using the symmetric algorithm
                using (var cypherKey = symmetricCypher.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
                using (var fsOut = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(fsOut, cypherKey, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    fsIn.CopyTo(cs);
                }
            }
        }

        public static byte[] DecryptData(byte[] data, string ChannelId)
        {
            try
            {
                var publicKey = GetServerPrivateKey(ChannelId);

                var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
                encryptEngine.Init(false, publicKey);

                return encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(data, 0, data.Length);

            }
            catch (Exception eex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(eex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I'm getting the error on the server from sending from iOS devices.

https://ibb.co/2PtbW3j

The Key length used is 1024.

Any idea what could be making this kind of issue.

**After some more debugging i noticed that the file is received with different byte size *[byte size was 1985940 on sent it was received 1985942]* and its only on IOS devices**

we are using crossfileuploader to transfer files

Comment: there are a dozen other questions with the same error message, have you read any of them to see if they apply to your problem?

Comment: *Length of data to decrypt is invalid*. So what is the length of the data?

Comment: I checked other answers. but the thing the same file is working from Android devices .

Comment: @JamesKPolk many retries this seems caused by the crossfileuploader i think.. the encrypted file byte size on device is 1985940 it is received on server  1985342 this case only shown on IOS devices not on android and the method used for encryption is on the PCL library.